# Use matplotlib animation.FuncAnimation after a button was pressed

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-animation

I want to create a live plot as soon as a button is pressed. The diagram is located in a `tkinter` window and is drawn with the `matplotlib` library. A minimal example of the code is shown below.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('1200x700+200+100')
        root.title('This is my root window')
        root.state('zoomed')
        root.config(background='#fafafa')

        self.xar = []
        self.yar = []

        style.use('ggplot')
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 4.5), dpi=100)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.line, = self.ax1.plot(self.xar, self.yar, 'r', marker='o')

        button = tk.Button(root, text="Plot", Command=self.print)
        button.grid()

        plotcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, root)
        plotcanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1, row=1)
        root.mainloop()

    def print(self):    
        canvas = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=1000, blit=False)

    def animate(self,i):
        self.yar.append(99-i)
        self.xar.append(i)
        self.line.set_data(self.xar, self.yar)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, i+1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test()
```

Comment: Change `button = tk.Button(..., Command=self.print())` to `button = tk.Button(..., command=self.print)`

Comment: Is still not working warning in the console is:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py:973: UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely unintended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable that exists for as long as you need the Animation.
  warnings.warn(

Comment: My suggestion should fix the `tkinter` side of your problem but it appears that there is another problem in how you handle `matplotlib`. I don't know that much about `matplotlib` so I can't help you with that part of your problem.